# Case when then, but with AND condition inside when and before then

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

In the below query I want to add an AND condition inside the CASE's WHEN and before THEN is that possible?

for example  WHEN 'r' AND table1.name="jones" THEN 'very high'

```
SELECT table1.id, table1.name,
   CASE table1.event
     WHEN 'r' THEN 'very high'
     WHEN 't' THEN 'very low'
     ELSE (SELECT table2.risk FROM table2 WHERE table2.value <= table1.value
           ORDER BY table2.value DESC LIMIT 1)
   END AS risk
FROM table1
ORDER BY FIELD( table1.event, 'r', 'f', 't' ), table1.value DESC
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can rewrite your statement like this to accomplish what you want

```
SELECT table1.id, table1.name,
   CASE 
     WHEN table1.event = 'r' AND table1.name = 'jones' THEN 'very high'
     WHEN table1.event = 't' AND table1.name = 'smith' THEN 'very low'
     ELSE (SELECT table2.risk FROM table2 WHERE table2.value <= table1.value
           ORDER BY table2.value DESC LIMIT 1)
   END AS risk
FROM table1
ORDER BY FIELD( table1.event, 'r', 'f', 't' ), table1.value DESC
```

notice that you need to remove `table1.event` after the `CASE` statement.
[documentation here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-statement.html)

Comment: +1, I was editing that idea into my answer when you posted this =)

Comment: @jadarnel217 haha thanks, I'll +1 your answer too, since it's the the same.

Answer (score 6):

Anything that evaluates to a boolean (true or false) can go in the `WHEN` condition of a `CASE` statement.  So you can replace `'r'` with:

`('r' AND table1.name='jones')`

Thinking about this more, you might have to lose the `table1.event` after `CASE`

```
SELECT table1.id, table1.name,
    CASE 
        WHEN (table1.event = 'r' AND table1.name='Jones') THEN 'very high'
        WHEN table1.event = 't' THEN 'very low'
        ELSE (SELECT table2.risk 
              FROM table2 
              WHERE table2.value <= table1.value 
              ORDER BY table2.value DESC LIMIT 1)
    END AS risk
FROM table1
ORDER BY FIELD( table1.event, 'r', 'f', 't' ), table1.value DESC
```

Answer (score 4):

Switch from `case <column> when <value> then ...` to `case when <condition> then ...`:

```
CASE 
WHEN table1.event = 'r' AND table1.active = 1 THEN 'very high'
...
```