# Use of AND in Case statements in MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, case

OK, the purpose of this query is to check if a record exists in table two and if it does update the type to duplicate, if it doesn't, then update it to original. I have to check on three fields, and all of them have to be true to qualify as a duplicate entry.

At this point, it does check the correct table, finds if there's a duplicate, and changes the status from 1 to 2 on all 9 of the records I test on, however, it's only changing the first record to "duplicate" even though they all are duplicates.

Am I able to use 'AND' in the case statement? If not, does anyone have a suggestion how I can alter this query to work? I've tried using a SELECT subquery, but that didn't work.

Here's the code:

```
$query = "UPDATE first_table f
    LEFT
    JOIN second_table s
      ON f.co_id = s.co_id
     SET f.status = 2, f.type = 
        CASE 
            WHEN s.ltt = f.ltt
            AND s.lang = f.lang 
            AND s.units = f.units
        THEN 'duplicate' ELSE 'original' 
        END
   WHERE f.co_id = :coid AND f.type = :rtype AND f.status = :status";
    $params = array();
    $params[] = array(':coid', $co_id, 'int');
    $params[] = array(':rtype', 'uploads', 'str');
    $params[] = array(':status', '1', 'int');
    $db->query($query, $params);
```

Comment: Take a look here: [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7294928/4670125)

Comment: I just did. They're using the case in a select to select an item, but it does show that "And" is acceptable. That answers a tiny bit, but still leaves me with the problem why it's only updating the first to duplicate, and leaving the rest as original, even though they're all duplicates. I'm certain it's something in my query I'm doing wrong, but CASE is fairly new to me...and I can't see it.

Comment: imo you can use AND. Have you tried to use brackets for the whole CASE structure? Otherwise sqlfiddle would help

Comment: Thanks, I'll give the brackets a try first, then if not...check out sqlfiddle. I appreciate the input

Answer (score 0):

I managed to use a little of the advice from Ali Arshad, and the sqlfiddle...and came up with the solution!

```
 $query = "UPDATE first_table f
LEFT
JOIN second_table s
  ON f.co_id = s.co_id
 SET f.status = 2, f.type = 
    CASE 
        WHEN (SELECT f.prop_id FROM first_table f 
                WHERE s.ltt = f.ltt AND s.lang = f.lang 
                AND s.units = f.units)
    THEN 'duplicate' ELSE 'original' 
    END
WHERE f.co_id = :coid AND f.type = :rtype AND f.status = :status";
$params = array();
$params[] = array(':coid', $co_id, 'int');
$params[] = array(':rtype', 'uploads', 'str');
$params[] = array(':status', '1', 'int');
$db->query($query, $params);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you're looking like is the follow link,

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

this command make automaticly the insert and update at the same time with the definitions you define.

Comment: That would have been nice, but we need to keep a record of what's duplicates, etc. in the first table as well. The answer I gave hits all of the points of our needs.